# Building a regex that is indifferent to text in the middle of the string between matches

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm dealing with strings that can come in any shape or size. I built my initial regex to match cashtags or symbols like `$fb`:

`/( ?[$]\w{3,5} ?){3,}/`

So for a string like `"I like stocks $fb $goog $aapl"`, it works.

For a string like `"I like $fb and other stocks like $goog and $aapl"`, it doesn't work.

How can I alter my regex to achieve this end. Basically recognizing 3+ 3-5 char `a-zA-z` strings preceded by `$`?

Thanks!

Comment: `(?:.*(?:[$][a-zA-Z]{3,5}).*){3,}` Link: https://regex101.com/r/dvDjaN/2

Comment: It is not possible to "ignore"/"be indifferent to" text inside a single match. You might want to use mulitple matching, just use `"\\B\\$\\w{3,5}\\b"` to extract all of them. If you need a specific amount of them in the string, just count the matches while you access them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a tad confused by the question, but I think I can cover all cases with the answer - you are looking for a match when any string contains three or more "merge variables", like $*varname*, where *varname* is 3-5 characters.  The confusion comes from your example because $fb doesn't match this criteria.  In any case, this pattern in java or javascript does what you want (with *varname* being 2-5 characters to accommodate "$fb"):

```
(?:\$\w{2,5}[^$]+){3,}
```

Where (?:*pattern*) denotes a non-capturing group.  This successfully matches both of your sample strings.

Note that if your aim is to also capture the variables themselves in groups this approach will not work, as a "capturing group" inside the non-capturing group will only capture the last match in any regex implementation I've used.  If this is your aim, you will be better off simply matching the variables in capturing groups and then testing whether or not you captured 3 or more matches.

*NOTE:* I realize I am not using the implementation that you state in your question, but I doubt that anything I've used here is not available in some form in the technology you are working with.